# What to do if Inputs for Togaf are not present?

Tags: togaf

I am reading up on Togaf Data Architecture. A lot of inputs are mentioned.

Does the framework propose any methods or mechanisms (without being over prescriptive) what to do if the inputs are not available? What are the implications if some are not available?

Preferred answers refer to Togaf.

If Togaf has no answer, personal opinions are welcome as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TOGAF does encourage tailoring the framework to fit organization and stakeholder's need, including Content Tailoring which you can customize artifacts and deliverables used in ADM.

So, instead of "what to do if lots of inputs are not available", I think that you can determine what inputs are critical and what inputs could be optional in Preliminary Phase step 5.3.5 "Tailor the TOGAF Framework".

Another suggestion from TOGAF about how to deal with shortage of artifacts:

> In fact, the first execution of the ADM will often be the hardest, since the architecture assets available for re-use will be relatively scarce. Even at this stage of development, however, there will be architecture assets available from external sources such as the TOGAF standard, as well as the IT industry at large, that could be leveraged in support of the effort.

While IMHO it is less practical to look external sources (it is less likely that other companies in your industry will share their EA works with you), there are indeed some reference architectures such as https://publications.opengroup.org/p180 which might give you some more ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If the Input is required, and the Input Artifacts are not made available, then I would say, from just a Project Management Perspective, you need to escalate the lack of those deliverables to the appropriate level (PM, Stakeholders, etc.), so that they can get prioritized and assigned to the appropriate individuals.  This will also make sure that people in leadership know that there are things that need to be done by others in order for the solution to be successful.  And if they're not willing to make it a priority for the people who have the knowledge, then it will call that to light.

Or, and this is more likely in my experience, you roll up your sleeves and go produce the Input Artifacts yourself.  That's also going to give you a better understanding of what's going on, which in turn will allow the Architecture you're developing to be more solid and robust.

Comment: I like it - though rolling up the sleeves might and do others work might give the wrong signal to management. I might work 1y to get something else right (that no-one wants/needs but me) ...

Comment: I get what you're saying, and optimally, we shouldn't HAVE to do other people's work.  But, like you said, it's a Required Input, so you have to have it to do YOUR job.  Present the need to management, along with the Role\Person you believe should be doing it.  Management may or may not have them do it, but odds are YOUR delivery date won't change.  So do the work, learn more, and at end of year, list it as an item on your 'Exceeded Expectations List'.  It's rare to be penalized for knowing MORE than your Role is expected to know.